# Puzzling Android xmlns error

Tags: android

I have come across code like this in many maps examples:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However, for them all, it goes that I get error

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Unexpected namespace prefix
>   "xmlns" found for tag
>   fragment  activity_msmap.xml  /example/res/layout line 8  Android Lint
>   Problem

At line

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

So... What is going on here? I see it in examples everywhere, but it causes error in my  Eclipse/Android? Also, why repeat the same xml namespace when it is also defined in the parent element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't define a namespace twice in an xml layout.
Just remove it from your fragment, the RelativeLayout already defines the xmlns:android namespace.

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```